# Чтобы комментатор не был ссылкой, а лишь как текст. K2 в joomla

Tags: php, joomla3, gtk2

Нужна ваша помощь, я не очень-то разбираюсь... Имеется сайт на joomla, со статьями на K2, в которых автор комментария отображается ссылкой, а не как обычный текст. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы автор комментария отображался не ссылкой, а был как обычный текст?[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Удалите ссылку в шаблоне комментариев. Или через CSS ее закройте.

```
.yourlink {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```